# Insert operation pause while fetch large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, fetch, sql-insert

I am continuously inserting value into table 3 table having same structure

```
    Table1 (col1 bigint primary key,col2 bigint,col3 int,col4 datetime,col5 varchar(400),col6 float,
    col7 numeric(18,6),col8 numeric(18,6),col9 float,col10 datetime,col11 int,col12 int,col13 bit,col14 varchar(20),col15 varchar(10))

Table2 (col1 bigint primary key,col2 bigint,col3 int,col4 datetime,col5 varchar(400),col6 float,
col7 numeric(18,6),col8 numeric(18,6),col9 float,col10 datetime,col11 int,col12 int,col13 bit,col14 varchar(20),col15 varchar(10))

Table3 (col1 bigint primary key,col2 bigint,col3 int,col4 datetime,col5 varchar(400),col6 float,
col7 numeric(18,6),col8 numeric(18,6),col9 float,col10 datetime,col11 int,col12 int,col13 bit,col14 varchar(20),col15 varchar(10))
```

I Store Data in Table1  for 1 day in Table2 for week and in Table3 for One Month On every day at midnight 1 am I delete yesterday data from Table1, 7 days ago data from Table2

when month change I change month table table3 (table3_jan,table3_feb etc)

I have set Non-index on all  tables (column col2 and col4)

Currently I have 30 GB data in table3_sept and on daily basis it goes increases

data inserted rapidly in above 3 table

**Now when I fetch 15 days Data from Table3 and insert into #temp table. 
all insert operation get pasued when query get execute then 
insert operation get resume.**

```
select * into #temp from table3 or other table where date between '1 aug 2017' and '17 aug 2017' order by id desc
```

So my quetion is how to avoid that pause process
Is their any wrong table structure I have created 
Kindly help me on high priority.Thanks

Comment: Creating a table for each month is not good design. Create one table for all, add a datetime column (`Added` or something like that) to differentiate between months.

Comment: I wonder why you're splitting it in 3 tables like this instead of putting it all in one table and differentiating between months. This way, you duplicate a lot of data and have a lot of duplicate processes and room for error (For example, if you concated this to one table, you wouldn't need to delete anything and you wouldn't have to move anything).

Comment: for fast result view i just created that structure.
users only fetch one day data mostly and week they are only use months data rarely. Previous I have same structure as you guys suggested but for result view I just changed this

Comment: >>>I have set Non-index on all tables (column col2 and col4)<<< what does it mean? Your tables have no indexes at all?

Comment: I have set non-index on day table,week table and month table on column field (col2 bigint and col4 datetime) for search become more fast cause on daily basis 7 millions entries get inserted.